# Jax-WS - When implementing a Web Service, can you call another web service like calling any pojo?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, pojo

Suppose I have the following 2 web service code, I think I can do the following

```
 @WebService  
 public class WS1  {     
    @WebMethod  
    public String hello() {   
        WS2 ws2 = new WS2();  
        ws2.method2();  
  }   

 @WebService  
  public class WS2 {   
 @WebMethod  
    public String method2() {  
     //implementation of method2.  
  }
```

I've tested and it worked. Now the question is: is there any side effect or unforeseen consequences that I am not aware of if I do this? Can I call the 2nd web service object like any normal pojo from server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that will work in terms of basic code execution.  however, the ws2 instance you instantiate will not have any "container managed" stuff done to it.  e.g., dependency injection won't work, any transaction/security support for that service will be ignored, etc.  in other words, it's probably not what you want to do in the general case.